# JSon in MVC4 using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, json, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to JavaScript....
I have data in database......
I get it by using linQ as follows

```
 public List<SelectListItem> getTokens()
    {
        var tokens = from T in db.tokens select T;
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var t in tokens)
        {
          items.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = t.id.ToString(), Text = t.tname });
        }

        return items.ToList<SelectListItem>;
 }
```

Or

```
 public string getTokens()
 {
  var tokens = from T in db.tokens select T;
  string s = "[";
        foreach (var t in tokens)
        {
            s += "{ id:" + t.id.ToString() + ", name: " + t.tname + "},";
        }
        s += "]";
        return s;
}
```

i want to pass that string/List to my JS function something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#demo-theme").tokenInput([
            { id: 7, name: "Ruby" },
            { id: 11, name: "Python" },
            { id: 13, name: "JavaScript" },
            { id: 17, name: "ActionScript" },
            { id: 19, name: "Scheme" },
            { id: 23, name: "Lisp" },
            { id: 29, name: "C#" },
            { id: 31, name: "Fortran" },
            { id: 37, name: "Visual Basic" },
            { id: 41, name: "C" },
            { id: 43, name: "C++" },
            { id: 47, name: "Java" }],
            {theme: "ab"
        });
    });
```

I need to replace the first list of items with my string/list...
Or any other way to pass....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there with your second one, you just need to convert it to a JSON response and there is no need to try to serialise it yourself.

```
public JsonResult getTokens()
{
    return Json(db.tokens.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then this will return from an AJAX request , exactly what you want to pass into that javascript method (assuming a token has no extra properties you want to strip out).

**Update**: 
Jquery Ajax Documentation can be found at: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

However, let me offer you a simple alternative in case you are just trying to get an object into JavaScript and it doesn't need/want to be asynchronous. You can simply update your MVC ViewModel with a field which lists all your tokens and pass this into the script in your view.

```
public ActionResult YourExistingAction()
{
    YourExistingViewModel model = new YourExistingViewModel();
    model.Tokens = db.tokens.ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

Then with your view:

```
@model YourExistingViewModel

<script>
    var tokens = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Tokens));
    $(function() {
        $("#demo-theme").tokenInput(tokens, { theme: "ab" });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public JsonResult getTokens()
{
    var tokens = from T in db.tokens select T;
    var items = tokens.Select(t =>
        new SelectListItem { Value = t.id.ToString(), Text = t.tname });

    return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```